# How to allow users to 'add' values to a multi-value field but not edit any previously add values?

Tags: 7, rules

I have a field called 'Remarks' on an ECK entity (not a node) and Role A is allowed to leave remarks but I don't want them to edit previous remarks, I just want to give them the option to add one. Note: they are not the author or owner of the entity. Right now, I use an Edit Page Variant for this entity that they have access to and where this form for 'field_remarks' appears. The problem is that the previously added remarks are still showing up and therefore now they can still edit someone else's remarks.

### potential solution 1

I would probably be possible to hide the fields that already contain values with jQuery but that is not really the Drupal way, I believe.

### potential solution 2

Could it possibly be done with a Rules component that adds the value (text) to this field programmatically? And if so, how and where to show a text field that would accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically disable them in module like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   if($form_id == 'eck__entity__form_edit_ENTITY_NAME_BUNDLE_NAME') {
     $lang = $form['field_name']['#language'];
     foreach ($form['field_name'][$lang] as $key => $value) {
       if (is_numeric($key) && !empty($value['value']['#default_value'])) {
         $form['field_name'][$lang][$key]['value']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
       }
     }
   }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much No Sssweat ! I'll try that and provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer Using jQuery:

Like so we can check which fields have contain a something (a value).

```
$( "table#field-remarks-values > tbody > tr textarea" )
.not( "textarea:empty" )
.parentsUntil("tbody")
.addClass("hidden");
```

Maybe a better way is to remove them entirely:

```
$( "table#field-remarks-values > tbody > tr textarea" )
.not( "textarea:empty" )
.parentsUntil("tbody")
.remove();
```

This may be more difficult to bring them up again if at all.

It's a solution that works for now but not the best solution in my opinion.